# how to expand the list on clicking the arrow as youtube

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm an Android developer, I just want to expand the list as show in this image and I indicate it by red arrow when I click it, the list should be expand just like Youtube.

Please suggest me what should I do. How can I expand this on arrow click. If there is any suggestion for it please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `ListView` with

```
<ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandalelistView"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) blog will help you assists what you want.

Comment: this is realy good example but i just want to list like as YouTube as arrow click list expend if you saw the you tube list please help me i want that type of list not an expandable list as you mention in this post.